# Prevent dependency from being imported transitively in Gradle?

Tags: spring, gradle, dependencies, log4j, slf4j

### Background

I am creating a library for internal use in Spring-Boot projects. The library I am writing, using Gradle, has an unavoidable dependency on log4j2 since it is a logging library. Here is the dependency in question:

```js
implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.14.1'
```

Spring-Boot has its own implicit dependency on Logback. When importing my library into a Spring project, it creates the following error:

```shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/alexandre.meddin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.14.1/9a40554b8dab7ac9606089c87ae8a5ba914ec932/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/alexandre.meddin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

It is possible to subdue this error with the following Gradle configuration in my Spring project's build.gradle:

```js
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl') using module('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:0.0.0')
    }
}
```

### Question

Is it possible to solve this conflict *inside* the library? That is, use the required dependency but not expose it to the importing project? This way the conflict will be solved for all future users of the library, instead of needing to be debugged anew every time someone unfamiliar uses it.

Answer (score 0):

## compileOnly

Use `compileOnly` instead of `implementation`. This would have been solved in a heartbeat if I'd read the documentation more closesly. Problem solved.

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies